# I loved her when I first saw her

Tags: verb-usage

Is the following sentence okay? Does the "love" mean "fall in love with"?

> I loved her when I first saw her.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @RonaldSole It seems unusual to me. What do you think?

Comment: This sounds like you loved the first encounter with her. Maybe its her appearance or gesture or something else.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to me, because it claims simultaneity between a verb that usually describes a state (love), and an event (when I first saw her).

It would make more sense to say
*I've loved her since I first saw her.*

On the other hand, you might say
*I loved her manner when I first saw her.*
where *love* describes a reaction more than a persistent state.

Comment: If a man was grieving at the death of his wife, I can see nothing wrong with **I loved her when I first saw her**.

Answer (score -2):

I think the sentence should be

> I have loved her when I first saw her.

Because the simple past tense describes something that happened in the past and is no longer happening now and the present perfect tense describes something that happened in the past and continued up to the present.

Comment: No, the answer is wrong. The sentence you suggest is not grammatical. There was nothing wrong with the OP's suggestion. You don't use a time reference, as in your suggested answer, after the present perfect tense.

Comment: ah, time reference, I got it.